# Aggregate between start date and date before last in MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

Below member returns me Running Total between first and chosen date. It's possible to aggregate data up to one day/week/month before?

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[SUM] AS
AGGREGATE(
    NULL:TAIL(EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].Members).Item(0), 
    [Measures].[X]
)
```

Here is example (date can be a day, month, year...) :

```
DATE X SUM
------------
 1   1 NULL
 2   4  1
 3   2  5
 4   2  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've almost got it - to end the aggregation x number of days before you can use lag:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[SUM] AS
AGGREGATE(
    NULL
   :
    TAIL(
      EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].Members
    ).Item(0).lag(7) //<<<< finishes 7 days before chosen date
  ,[Measures].[X]
)
```